# Angular router is not working but there is no errors aswell

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I have two router files **auth_router.js** and **teacher_router.js**. the **auth_router.js** is working fine but the **teacher_router.js** is not working. the code is below:

app.js file

```
angular.module("learn_mart", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
    .run(function($rootScope, $cookies) {
        $rootScope.baseurl = "http://localhost/lm/auth.html#";

        $rootScope.userrole = $cookies.get('userrolecookie');
        $rootScope.activetab = $cookies.get('activetabcookie');


        $rootScope.redirectologin = function(role) {
            $cookies.put('activetabcookie', 1);
            $cookies.put('userrolecookie', role);

            window.location = $rootScope.baseurl + '/' + role + "_login";
        };
    });
```

auth_router.js file

```
angular.module("learn_mart")
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/sub_login", {
                controller: "subscriber_login",
                templateUrl: 'views/auth/subscriber_login.html'
            })
            .when("/sub_register", {
                controller: "subscriber_registration",
                templateUrl: 'views/auth/subscriber_registration.html'
            })
            .when("/tech_login", {
                controller: "teacher_login",
                templateUrl: 'views/auth/teacher_login.html'
            })
            .when("/tech_register", {
                controller: "teacher_registration",
                templateUrl: 'views/auth/teacher_registration.html'
            })
            .when("/shop_login", {
                controller: "shop_login",
                templateUrl: 'views/auth/shop_login.html'
            })
            .when("/shop_register", {
                controller: "shop_registration",
                templateUrl: 'views/auth/shop_registration.html'
            })
    });
```

teacher_router.js

```
angular.module("learn_mart")
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/teacher_course", {
                controller: "show_courses_teacher",
                templateUrl: "views/auth/shop_login.html"
            })
    });
```

There is no issue's with the file inclution. Also there is no errors shown in the developer console.

Comment: I believe only a single `.config` per Angular module is allowed. If you need to have multiple `.config`s then you'll have to use different modules and inject the child module into the parent.

Comment: It turns out my assumption is incorrect. [The documentation on modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) clearly indicates that multiple `.config` sections are allowed.